# Unable to access ReorderableListview.builder and No physics property in ReorderableListview in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I was trying to create a ReorderableListview, but found that there is no "physics" property available in it.

Later figured out that we have ReorderableListview.builder constructor which has "physics" property defined: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView/ReorderableListView.builder.html

Now, the issue is I cannot access ReorderableListview.builder. Please find the attached image for reference of the issue [Issue of accessing the builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njF5V.png)

Has anyone has the example of ReorderableListview.builder ? Or worked with it?

My main moto is to add physics to ReorderableListview.

An example of ReorderableListview.builder will be helpful and appreciated.

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView/physics.html It's already there, which flutter version and branch are you using?

Comment: Hi @MaadhavSharma Please find the attached image for the same. While accessing the builder I get an error " The method 'builder' isn't defined for the type 'ReorderableListView'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'builder'."

Comment: I am using flutter Flutter 1.22.3 @MaadhavSharma

Comment: Please upgrade to the latest version, the physics property, and the builder both are present in the latest version 2.0.1

Comment: Okay Thank you soo much @MaadhavSharma

Comment: Welcome, let me know if it worked